# How to transform cells in an excel worksheet that occupy two rows into a single row?

Tags: excel

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r3bj.jpg]

As shown in the figure above, we have got some cells that occupy two rows in our excel worksheet. We found such cells could not be processed with python. Therefore, we would like to transform those cells into the form of a single row as follows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbmxy.jpg]

How to implement such a transformation process? Alternatively, is there a way to save those data items in some other specific way and process them with python?

I just care about column A and column B and column C can be ignored. I could even drop column C if needed.

Comment: Highlight merged cells and click the *Merge* button under the Home tab of your ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

In excel, you can solve this directly by copying relevant columns with an array formula.

In python, I would suggest the [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package. Read your data columnwise, excluding for prespecified columns.